# Magento2 composer installation project-community-edition vs community-edition

Tags: magento, magento2

When I tried to install magento2 via composer I have found 2 installation repository on composer.

1. magento/community-edition
2. magento/project-community-edition

What is the different between this repository and which one is recommend for start magento development.

Answer (score 1):

`magento/community-edition` is the same Magento2 codebase as that available on [github.com](https://github.com/magento/magento2). This is meant for contributing developers, i.e. those that want to contribute features and fixes to the magento code-base. More details can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/contributor-guide/contributing.html)

`magento/project-community-edition` is the Magento2 package that is ready to go in production mode. This gives system integrators and extension developers more flexibility in managing packages and testing their extensions respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`magento/project-community-edition` is correct.

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>`

as shown in [our documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce)